# Python - How can i print a certain dictionary field from many dictionaries within a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printing, output

I am currently working on a Guess Who like game for school work and I cannot seem to get this to work. What I am trying to do is get the field "Name" printed from all the dictionaries below within a list.

```
 Greg = {"Name":"Greg", "HairLength":"Short", "HairColour":"Brown", "FacialHair":"Yes", "Jewellery":"Yes", "Hat":"No", "Lipstick":"No", "Gender":"Male"}

 Chris = {"Name":"Chris", "HairLength":"Long", "HairColour":"Blonde", "FacialHair":"No", "Jewellery":"No","Hat":"Yes", "Lipstick":"Yes", "Gender":"Male"}

 Jason = {"Name":"Jason", "HairLength":"Short", "HairColour":"Brown", "FacialHair":"Yes", "Jewellery":"No","Hat":"Yes", "Lipstick":"No", "Gender":"Male"}

 Clancy = {"Name":"Clancy", "HairLength":"Bald", "HairColour":"Red", "FacialHair":"Yes", "Jewellery":"No", "Hat":"No","Lipstick":"No", "Gender":"Male"}

 Betty = {"Name":"Betty", "HairLength":"Short", "HairColour":"Blonde", "FacialHair":"No", "Jewellery":"Yes","Hat":"Yes", "Lipstick":"Yes", "Gender":"Female"}

 Helen = {"Name":"Helen", "HairLength":"Short", "HairColour":"Brown", "FacialHair":"No", "Jewellery":"No", "Hat":"No","Lipstick":"Yes", "Gender":"Female"}

 Selena = {"Name":"Selena", "HairLength":"Long", "HairColour":"Brown", "FacialHair":"No", "Jewellery":"Yes","Hat":"No", "Lipstick":"No", "Gender":"Female"}

 Jacqueline = {"Name":"Jacqueline", "HairLength":"Long", "HairColour":"Red", "FacialHair":"Yes", "Jewellery":"Yes", "Hat":"No","Lipstick":"No", "Gender":"Female"}


AISuspects = ([Greg, Chris, Jason, Clancy, Betty, Selena, Helen,
Jacqueline])
UserSuspects = ([Greg, Chris, Jason, Clancy, Betty, Selena, Helen, Jacqueline])

print("AISuspects:")
#Here i want it to print the field "Name" in every dictionary within the list AISuspects 


print("UserSuspects:")
#Here i want it to print the field "Name" in every dictionary within the list UserSuspects
```

Expected output and current output after the solution:

AI Suspects:
['Greg', 'Chris', 'Jason', 'Clancy', 'Betty', 'Selena', 'Helen', 'Jacqueline']

User Suspects:
['Greg', 'Chris', 'Jason', 'Clancy', 'Betty', 'Selena', 'Helen', 'Jacqueline']

Comment: You don't need the parentheses `()` around your `AISuspects` and `UserSuspects` lists. Just creating the list with the `[]` will suffice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to get a list of all the suspects' names

```
suspects_names = [suspect['Name'] for suspect in AISuspects]
```

Then you can use `print(' '.join(suspect_names))`

If you don't mind printing each name in a new line, just use a for loop:

```
for suspect in AISuspects:
    print(suspect['Name'])
```

Take care of those parenthesis around the lists definitions, you don't need them and they're usually used to define tuples, so I'd get rid of them

Comment: Im slightly confused could you expand rather know why that works than just know it works and i can move on... Thanks

Comment: @ComputerExpert69 Can you be specific about what part you are confused about exactly? I think the first solution offered using the comprehension is something you probably haven't learned yet. The second solution might look more familiar to you.

Comment: Oh sorry i did not realised you edited your post, yes i do understand that second solution thanks!

Comment: @ComputerExpert69 If this solution helped you, please make sure you mark it as accepted (the checkmark next to this answer).

Comment: Another question, i am getting the expected output but it is being repeated:

Comment: Sorry this does work, but my output is being repeated and i have found a much simpler solution. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @ComputerExpert69 Could you share the output you're getting and what you're expecting?

Comment: @Francisco27 Sure

Comment: I think that your solution is actually amazing! But i only needed the names from the dictionaries and nothing else, it is very simple wheras you would expect something very advanced.

Comment: @ComputerExpert69 Hopefully this wasn't taken personally, but part of the push to choose the better solution is also for future readers who might run in to this question and are looking for a helpful solution, this one would be the one that would help the most.

Comment: No, of course no hard feelings. You are totally right this is a better solution for future readers thats my bad.

Answer (score -1):

```
UserSuspects = [Greg['Name'], Chris['Name'],Jason['Name'], Clancy['Name'], Betty['Name'], Selena['Name'], Helen['Name'], Jacqueline['Name']]


print UserSuspects
```

Comment: This a much simpler solution, and i was getting errors from the other solutions so i shall make you this questions solution ;)

Comment: Accepting this solution doesn't make any sense @ComputerExpert69 when the other one is clearly the better solution here and *the* way to solve this problem.

Comment: How exactly is it a "better" solution? @idjaw

Comment: @ComputerExpert69 what if you also need a new suspect called `John`? Or maybe 200 more? And how does it answer your question of "*How can i print a certain dictionary field from many dictionaries within a list?*"

Comment: In the other answer, they offered you a way to loop through every element of your dictionary. In real life situations, you will need to expand and contract your dictionaries (adding and removing keys and values). This solution will cause errors at worst, and make you manually rectify the print statement at best. Therefore, you should put in some efforts to understand the other, better, solution. [ :

Comment: It's a "better" solution, because it is the idiomatic way of solving this sort of problem. What are you going to do if you have to print other properties from that dictionary? Are you going to keep creating more and more lists like that? Instead, you can just create a single loop that goes through your lists and access the needed data

Comment: @Andras Deak, you are correct his solution is "better" it not be as simple but it certainly is coded alot better